# Загрузка img через URL в форму JavaScript

Tags: javascript, изображения, url, img

Есть форма, ввожу в нее ссылку на картинку (http://......ru) и она должна добавлять ее в div фоном . Сейчас при вводе ссылки - в div записывается сама ссылка(то есть текст). Не знаю как сделать так,чтобы ссылка подгружала изображение и менялся background-image.

```
     const  containers = document.querySelector('.places-list');
const addForm = document.querySelector('.popup__button');
const form = document.querySelector('.popup__form');





function newCard(nameValue, linkValue) {
  const container = document.createElement('div');
  const inputLink = document.createElement('div');
  const inputName = document.createElement('h3');
  //*


//*
  container.classList.add('place-card');

  inputLink.classList.add('place-card__image');
  inputLink.textContent = linkValue; 

  inputName.classList.add('place-card__name');
  inputName.textContent = nameValue;

  container.appendChild(inputLink);
  container.appendChild(inputName);

  return container;
}

function addCard(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  const name = form.elements.name;
  const link = form.elements.link;

  const container = newCard(name.value, link.value);
  containers.appendChild(container);

  name.value = '';
  link.value = '';

}

openedForm.addEventListener("click", formClick);
form.addEventListener('submit', addCard);
```

Comment: Вы бы код свой показали для начала.

Comment: @rabbit сделано

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var imageUrl = "https://...";
element.style.backgroundImage = `url(${imageUrl})`;
```

```js
var imageUrl = "https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/fruits.png";
document.querySelector("#test").style.backgroundImage = `url(${imageUrl})`;
```

```css
#test {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: спасибо вам))))

Comment: @Pavel Пожалуйста. Успехов!